# How to pin tabs below the app bar when scrolling over

Tags: flutter

Which widgets to be used to pin tabs as below. Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without additional package by using [SliverMainAxisGroup](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverMainAxisGroup-class.html) to make SliverAppBar pinned up and the content above will hidden while scrolled down.

Sample code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const SliverMainAxisGroupExampleApp());

class SliverMainAxisGroupExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const SliverMainAxisGroupExampleApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('App Bar')),
        body: const SliverMainAxisGroupExample(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SliverMainAxisGroupExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const SliverMainAxisGroupExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.cyan,
            height: 100,
            child: Text('To be hidden', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24)),
          ),
        ),
        SliverMainAxisGroup(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            const SliverAppBar(
              title: Text('Pinned tabs'),
              expandedHeight: 70.0,
              pinned: true,
            ),
            SliverList.builder(
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  color: index.isEven ? Colors.amber[300] : Colors.blue[300],
                  height: 100.0,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Item $index',
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              itemCount: 10,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the result:

[image: sticky]

Hopefully it can solve your problem, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Sticky_headers](https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_headers), easy to implement.

Lets you place headers on scrollable content that will stick to the top of the container whilst the content is scrolled.